# Implement multi textures in the FabricJS

Tags: webgl, fabricjs

I am trying to implement glsl code in the frontend through FabricJS library
https://gl-transitions.com/editor/windowslice

here is my code snippet

```
// calling this method so that CustomWebglFilter will be initialized and we can utilize this effect later

function initEffect() {
  fabric.Image.filters.CustomWebglFilter = fabric.util.createClass(
    fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter,
    {
      type: "CustomWebglFilter",

      vertexSource: `
      attribute vec2 aPosition;
      varying vec2 tc;

      void main( void )
         {
           gl_Position = vec4( aPosition, 0.0, 1.0 );
           tc    = (gl_Position.xy + vec2(1.0)) / vec2(2.0);
         }
      `,
      fragmentSource: `
precision highp float;
uniform float count; // = 10.0
uniform float smoothness; // = 0.5
uniform float progress;
uniform sampler2D uTargetImage;
uniform sampler2D uSourceImage;

vec4 getToColor(vec2 p) {
    return texture2D(uTargetImage, p);
}

vec4 getFromColor(vec2 p) {
    return texture2D(uSourceImage, p);
}

vec4 transition (vec2 p) {
  float pr = smoothstep(-smoothness, 0.0, p.x - progress * (1.0 + smoothness));
  float s = step(pr, fract(count * p.x));
  return mix(getFromColor(p), getToColor(p), s);
}

varying vec2 tc;

void main() {
  //vec4 tex1 = transition(tc);
  gl_FragColor = transition(tc);
}
`,
      mainParameter: "progress",
      progress: 0,
      smoothness: 0,

      applyToWebGL(options) {
        const gl = options.context;
        gl.viewport(0.7, 0.7, fabricCanvas.width, fabricCanvas.height);
        const shader = this.retrieveShader(options);
        const program = shader.program;
        gl.useProgram(program);

        const uTrgetTexture = createAndBindTexture(gl, targetImage);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, uTrgetTexture);
       /*  const uSourceTexture = createAndBindTexture(gl, sourceImage);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 1);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, uSourceTexture); */

        options.aPosition = new Float32Array([
          -1,
          1, // bottom left corner
          1,
          1, // bottom right corner
          -1,
          -1, // top left corner
          1,
          -1, // top right corner
        ]);

        this.sendAttributeData(
          gl,
          shader.attributeLocations,
          options.aPosition
        );
      },

      getUniformLocations: function (gl, program) {
        return {
          progress: gl.getUniformLocation(program, "progress"),
          smoothness: gl.getUniformLocation(program, "smoothness"),
        };
      },
      sendUniformData: function (gl, uniformLocations) {
        gl.uniform1f(uniformLocations.progress, this.progress);
        gl.uniform1f(uniformLocations.smoothness, this.smoothness);
      },
    }
  );
}

fabric.Image.filters.CustomWebglFilter.fromObject = function () {
  return new fabric.Image.filters.CustomWebglFilter();
};

// For Creating and binding textures
function createAndBindTexture(gl, image) {
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image); // Send the Image from CPU to GPU
  return texture;
}
```

along with this I also reviewed the inbuild [BlendFilter](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/src/filters/BlendImage.ts) for the mutiTexture but it's not working as expected.

If any one has tried with muti textures in fabricjs please share the solution that will be great.

Thanks